# Conversion from void* to object in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, garbage-collection, unsafe

In a C# project, I need to pass object parameters by putting references in a structure.
i.e. I have a structure passed to a dispatcher

```
struct SOMESTRUCT
{
    public int lpObject;
}
```

Where lpObject holds a pointer to a custom object like

```
class SomeClass
{
    private string foo;
}
```

And the SOMESTRUCT structure is passed from method to method to finally reach my code. I cannot modify the execution flow nor the strange SOMSTRUCT system, so I guessed the only solution was to cast my object to a pointer like this :

```
var myObject = new SomeClass();
GCHandle GC = GCHandle.Alloc(myObject, GCHandleType.Pinned);
int myRef = GC.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt32();
GC.Free();

SOMESTRUCT struct;
struct.lpObject = myRef;
someMethod(struct);
```

However, I can't figure out how to retrieve the myObject members from the lpObject fields. Something like this:

```
SomeClass myObject = CastPointerToObject(struct.myRef) as SomeClass;
```

Is there a way to do it, or is it impossible ? How can I tell the garbage collector to handle the object ? Should I create a new Garbage-collected object and copy the data field by field ?

TYIA,

Comment: use IntPtr instead of int .... so it will work in 64bit as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no No NO *NO* **NO!!!**

This

```
struct SOMESTRUCT
{
    public SomeClass object_ref;
}
```

Is the correct way to store a reference in a struct.

The code you have written, and the accepted answer, are 100% broken.

The address returned by `GC.AddrOfPinnedObject(GCHandle)` is only valid while the `GCHandle` is intact.  You must not call `GCHandle.Free`, and you must not let the `GCHandle` get collected.  In your code, the address is already meaningless by the time you store it.

But you should just let .NET take care of managing the pointer during garbage collection, by using a variable of reference type.  Then you don't need to jump through hoops.  The only reason to take the address of a managed object is when passing it to an existing native DLL function that will save the pointer after it returns.  For example, it's necessary with OpenGL buffer arrays.  It is NOT necessary, ever, when calling other C# methods.

If SOMESTRUCT is actually a native data type used by some DLL function you haven't mentioned, then you'll need to make sure to keep the `GCHandle` alive.  Only as long as the `GCHandle` exists will the pointer you got remain valid.

Comment: Agreed. The accepted answer is not correct; however I think there is more to the story we don't know, otherwise, why all the extra work when the runtime would manage the marshalling correctly?

Comment: @codekaizen: Yes, the requirement that "the SOMESTRUCT type cannot be changed" must have some rationale that we need to know in order to solve the program properly.

Comment: The SOMESTRUCT type is a window message struct with a "custom pointer". This pointer was originally used (in the program) to reference strings containing serialized objects, which worked (kind of) fine. In my code, some classes were not serializable so I had to come up with another solution. In fact, the accepted solution looked OK but was never tested, since it raised more problems that it solved; so I just gave up the "pointer/serialization" thing and used a more C#-ish way of doing things.

Comment: If a function needs to make an object available for *asynchronous* interaction between managed and unmanaged code (e.g. to play a sound), it may be appropriate to pin the object.  One must then devise a means of knowing when the unmanaged code is really finished with the object.  A cardinal rule is that *the GC must at all times know about all references to every unpinned object*.  Any references the GC doesn't know about, which target unpinned objects, are liable to spontaneously turn into references to "random" memory.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to cast the returned pointer back to a struct?

Similar to:

```
lvHitTestInfo = (LVHITTESTINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lP, typeof(LVHITTESTINFO));
```

Where lvHitTestInfo is a structure and lp a pointer.

Or i didn't understand your question properly. Maybe you can explain more (more complete code sample).

Comment: Yes and no. I want to cast the returned pointer to an object. I will add more details to my question.

Comment: I didn't noticed that this methods works also with objects. This is what I was looking for. Thank you for your help !

Comment: I've never gone there but to know if that's possible you need to give an exact description of what is actually returned. What exactly does the pointer point to.

See, if you're interacting with unmanaged code it's very unlikely you will be able to cast to a managed object. There's no way knowing what goes where.

Comment: This would have worked to copy memory allocated by a native DLL function into a .NET object, but the question asked about a wild pointer into the managed heap, and there's no right way to recover that.